# Angular Route with Multiple slashes level not working

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I m facing a strange issue

http://localhost/people is working fine

http://localhost/people/aaa is NOT working

My httaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Route file is like this

```
        .when('/people/aaa', {
            templateUrl: 'sub/santosh-babu.php',
            controller: 'cntrl'
        })
        .when('/santosh-babu', {
            templateUrl:'sub/santosh-babu.php'
        })
```

i want "/people/aaa" to be replaces by "/people/:param" and use in route url and also want to retrieve value of param in "sub/santosh-babu.php?key=+param.param"

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your state definition ? How to you navigate from people to people/aaa ? <a href> ? `ui-sref` ? Is your application single page ?

Comment: currently i m not using any <a href> or anything else... I just want A URL /people/:param to route to page sub/santosh-babu.php... i straightforward type url (localhost/people/aaa) on brower and press enter...